# File.ReadAllLines doesn't work at webservice

Tags: c#, web-services

I wanna do read all lines from txt file and I use to it File.ReadAllLines.

At winforms it works fine.

But, when I', trying do the same at webservice at webmethod it crash

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Nie
>   można odnaleźć pliku 'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\nameOfFile.txt'.

CopyOutputToDirectory is set to copy always.

```
  string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("nameOfFIle.txt", Encoding.Default)
```

File is in webservice folder for webservice, and in application folder for application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a ASP.NET (WebForms or WebService) application you need to use something like:

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath(@"~/nameofFile.txt");
using (var reader = System.IO.File.OpenText(filePath))
{
     ... reader.ReadAllLines();
}
```

Assuming that the file is in the root of your WebService.

Comment: @phenevo, if the file is not in the root or subfolder of your app you should consider putting it there. The root (~) is your only point of reference.

Answer (score 5):

You need to obtain the web service root path and combine it with the filename if the file is in the root folder of your web service (where `web.config` file is located):

```
var path = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "nameOfFile.txt");
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.Default);
```

Answer (score 0):

The webservice is looking for the file at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\`, as indicated in the error message.

`CopyOutputToDirectory` would copy the file to the `bin` directory of the compiled webservice.

You need to pass the correct path to `File.ReadAllLines` - if you know the exact location, pass that through (you can try [`HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.applicationphysicalpath.aspx) for the base directory of the webservice).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, but it is not good fo r situation , where class which operating on this string file is in another folder.

I have folder Webservice and folder Server(there is this class)
In webservice folder i have webservice project, and in server folder i have library

(this is a way which I implementing Facade pattern)

The txt file is in server folder.